# defaultValue is pulling the last value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i click on a particular ToDos edit button, its value should be defaulted inside the textarea but everytime the last ToDo  is defaulting, can somebody please help, whether using ref is a right choice or something else, then where i m wrong what i'm suppose to do ?

```
 handleEdit() {
  e.preventDefault();
  .....

}  

renderDisplay() {
    return(
      <div>
       {
        this.props.listArr.map((list,i) => {
           return(
             <div key={i} index={i} ref="newText">
              <li>{list}
                <div>
                 <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
                         onClick={this.handleEdit.bind(this)}
                 />
                </div>
              <hr/>
              </li>
             </div>
           )})
       }
       </div>
    );
  }


  renderForm() {
   return(
      <div>
        <textarea className="form-control" defaultValue={this.refs.newText.innerText} rows="1" cols="100" style={{width: 500}}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
      if(this.state.editing) {
        return this.renderForm();
      }else {
        return this.renderDisplay();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using an [old ref API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs). You should use [this one](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs), where you set the ref to the instance of the class using `this` with a callback.

```
<input ref={ref => {this.myInput = ref}} />
```

And then you can access its value by just referring to `this.myInput` .

As for your "bug", keep in mind that you are looping over and overriding the ref. so the last ref assignment would be the last item in the array.

```
 this.props.listArr.map((list,i) => {
           return(
             <div key={i} index={i} ref="newText">
              <li>{list}
```

There will always be 1 `newText` ref and it will always be the last item in the array.

You should render different ref names according to the item `id` and then pass the `id` of the item to the `renderForm` so it can access the relevant ref.

With that said, i really recommend to extract the `todo` to a different component as well as the form. I don't see a valid reason to use refs in this case.

**Edit**
As a follow-up to your comment, here is a small example of how you would use components instead of refs in order to get information from the child like values etc..

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    const { todoId, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(todoId);
  }

  render() {
    const { value, complete } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        style={{ textDecoration: complete && 'line-through' }}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        {value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        { id: '1', value: 'to do this', complete: false },
        { id: '2', value: 'todo that', complete: true },
        { id: '3', value: 'will do it later', complete: false }]
    }
  }

  toggleTodo = (todoId) => {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    const nextState = todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id !== todoId) return todo;
      return {
        ...todo,
        complete: !todo.complete
      }
    });
    this.setState({ todos: nextState });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    return (
      <div >
        {
          todos.map((todo) => {
            return (
              <Todo
                complete={todo.complete}
                key={todo.id}
                todoId={todo.id}
                value={todo.value}
                onClick={this.toggleTodo}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How can i avoid this ref overriding or should i avoid ref ?

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer, you can avoid the ref override by providing different names. as for avoiding refs in general, just create components that handle their values and can send them back to the parent via the handlers.

Comment: I've added a running snippet example so you can get an idea.